# My User Update form is not showing up in my template

Tags: django

My User profile update form is not appearing in my template. I can only see 'Update' button and legend name. But I don't see the actual form.

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile, Post, User

# User = get_user_model()

class UserCreationModelForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'city', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'access_challenge']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email' ]
```

Here is my views.py 
I have two views. One is classed based view another one is function based view.

```
class CabinetView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

def profile(request):
    uform = UserUpdateForm()
    pform = ProfileUpdateForm()

    context = {
        'uform': uform,
        'pform': pform
    }

    return render(request, 'users/user_detail.html', context)
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegistrationView, CabinetView, PostCreateView, PostDetailView
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/', CabinetView.as_view(), name='cabinet'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/countries/', views.countries, name='countries'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/cities/<int:pk>/', views.cities, name='cities'),
    path('accounts/cabinet/address/<int:pk>/', views.address, name='address'),
```

And here is my user_detail.html template

```
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
          {{ uform }}
          {{ pform }}

        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn  btn-info btn-block" style="border-radius: 0; width: 200px; padding-left: 4px;" type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: And which of those URLs are you going to?

Comment: You don't have any URLs which make reference to your edit form.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, @Essex My URL is third from the top 
`    path('accounts/cabinet/', views.profile, name='profile'),`

Comment: But you have *two* URLs for accounts/cabinet. That can't work, Django will only ever use the first one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Isee. How can I add `def profile` function view to my `class CabinetView` class based view so I can have only one URL?

Comment: But that's not how it works either. You need to add the relevant context via methods that the class-based view already knows about, eg `get_context_data`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **CabinetView** class and **profile** def point to the same url.

So you need to change **profile** url to :

```
path('accounts/cabinet/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```